# Read memory with module base address

Tags: c#, memory, module, memory-address

How can I read a memory with module base address?
For example how can I read this memory: "winCap64.dll"+0x123456 + offsets.

I have added an example code of what I could produce after some research but I still cant read anything in C#. However the addresses are absolutely fine since they return me the correct value when I add them on Cheat Engine.

Edit: added samle code

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, Boolean bInheritHandle, UInt32 dwProcessId);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    byte[] lpBuffer, UIntPtr nSize, uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    static IntPtr Handle;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("process");
        Process nProcess = Processes[0];
        Handle = OpenProcess(0x10, false, (uint)nProcess.Id);
        IntPtr pointer = IntPtr.Add(nProcess.Modules[125].BaseAddress, 0x020C5150);
        int curhp = ReadOffset(pointer, 0x4D8);
        int curhp2 = ReadOffset((IntPtr)curhp, 0x0);
        int curhp3 = ReadOffset((IntPtr)curhp2, 0x1c0);
        Console.WriteLine(curhp3.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int ReadOffset(IntPtr pointer, uint offset)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[24];

        uint adress = (uint)ReadPointer(pointer) + offset;
        ReadProcessMemory(Handle, (IntPtr)adress, bytes, (UIntPtr)sizeof(int), 0);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    }

    public static int ReadPointer(IntPtr pointer)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[24];

        ReadProcessMemory(Handle, pointer, bytes, (UIntPtr)sizeof(int), 0);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need `nProcess.Modules[125].BaseAddress.ToInt64() + 0x02093458` in 64-bit-world?

Comment: @Ctx Probably a good idea to use `long` instead of `int` as well.

Comment: That will indeed solve the Arithmetic exception but why can't I still not read the memory?

Comment: IIRC a program with it's target architecture set to `Any CPU` wont be able to read memory for programs made to run specifically on `x86` or `x86_64` architectures, such as C/C++ programs and certain .NET programs. Try setting the project's 'Platform target' to `x64` in `Properties > Build`

Comment: In the sample above I believe it's only lack of coding. It should work if it is coded right.

Comment: Hmmm, do you remember the wonderful and marvelous exception "Attempt to read or write Protected Memory"? you can't access to another process memory unless you're a debugger or the memory has been explicitly shared by the process.

Comment: That would be correct but I know the specific memory can be read. I have actually read it in another programming language. As @user2530266 says, it is lack of coding. I think I am missing something here. It is my first memory read attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
IntPtr pointer = IntPtr.Add(nProcess.Modules[125].BaseAddress, BaseAddress);
Console.WriteLine("Final: " + pointer.ToString("X"));

int hp = ReadInt32(pointer, Handle);
string hexPrefix = "80" + hp.ToString("X"); //because int32 will cut some digits. I sugget using int64. Even UInt64.
long hexToint = long.Parse(hexPrefix, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
hp = ReadInt32((IntPtr)hexToint + 0x00, Handle);
hexPrefix = "80" + hp.ToString("X");
hexToint = long.Parse(hexPrefix, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
hp = ReadInt32((IntPtr)hexToint + 0x1c0, Handle);
hexPrefix = "80" + hp.ToString("X");
hexToint = long.Parse(hexPrefix, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
hp = ReadInt32((IntPtr)hexToint + 0x0, Handle);
```

Comment: That works! That's a hell of a debug. Nice workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`IntPtr` is the architecture agnostic way to store a pointer and pass it around, say to `ReadProcessMemory`:

```
IntPtr pointer = IntPtr.Add(nProcess.Modules[125].BaseAddress, 0x02093458);
```

Comment: That would solve the Arithmetic exception but I still can't read the memory. Updated the question with full sample code

Comment: When I add the memory on an engine and add the three offsets I can read it(example cheat engine or Artmoney). However I can't do that programmatically